# How can I change this code so instead of displaying line directions to a randomly spawned collectable item, it will point to a specific scene object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The bottom function is designed to be included with the function SpawnNewObject. It's supposed to spawn a collectable item to a random location in the map and draws a line from the user to that object.

My end goal is to be able to draw this line from the player to a pre-existing collectable object in the scene. How can I edit this function DrawPathToCollectable so it draws a path to the scene object?

```cs
    [SerializeField]
    private Collectable Prefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform Player;
    [SerializeField]
    private LineRenderer Path;
    [SerializeField]
    private float PathHeightOffset = 1.25f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float SpawnHeightOffset = 1.5f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float PathUpdateSpeed = 0.25f;

    private Collectable ActiveInstance;
    private NavMeshTriangulation Triangulation;
    private Coroutine DrawPathCoroutine;
    private Collectable ActiveInstance;

    private IEnumerator DrawPathToCollectable()
    {
        WaitForSeconds Wait = new WaitForSeconds(PathUpdateSpeed);
        NavMeshPath path = new NavMeshPath();

        while (ActiveInstance != null)
        {
            if (NavMesh.CalculatePath(Player.position, ActiveInstance.transform.position, NavMesh.AllAreas, path))
            {
                Path.positionCount = path.corners.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < path.corners.Length; i++)
                {
                    Path.SetPosition(i, path.corners[i] + Vector3.up * PathHeightOffset);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Unable to calculate a path on the NavMesh between {Player.position} and {ActiveInstance.transform.position}!");
            }

            yield return Wait;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So dont use a path array. Send the game object or its position

Comment: well as far as I can tell your code already does exactly that if you set the `ActiveInstance` (which btw exists twice in your provided code here) to your existing object accordingly ....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, to make it more generic, I would start the coroutine only if the target `Transform` is provided, something like that:

```
private Coroutine _showPathCoroutine;
private Transform _target;

public void SetTarget(Transform target)
{
    if (_target != null) StopCoroutine(_showPathCoroutine);
    _target = target;
    _showPathCoroutine = StartCoroutine(DrawPathToTarget);
}

private IEnumerator DrawPathToTarget()
{
    // same as DrawPathToCollectable (ActiveInstance replaced with _target)

    _showPathCoroutine = null;
}
```